# Build a vector from a list of indices

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I'm implementing the [NNLS algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_least_squares) for a final project for a class, and I'm trying to find an elegant way of building a new vector, w', from an existing vector w and a list of indexes P. My clunky solution is seen below.

```
function [w_prime] = vector_from_indices[w, P]
w_prime = zeros(numel(P));
for i = 1:numel(P)
    w_prime(i) = w(P(i));
end
end
```

Is there a way to do this elegantly in a line or more efficiently? I'm a CS major taking a higher-level math course, so I figured I'd apply the rigor of program aesthetics to my final project :)

NEW PROBLEM:

```
function [a] = minimizer(P, d, s)
a = d(P(1))/(d(P(1)) - s(P(1)));
for i =1:numel(P)
    if a > d(P(i))/(d(P(i)) - s(P(i)))
        a = d(P(i))/(d(P(i)) - s(P(i)));
    end
end
end

>> P 
P =
     1     3     4
>> d 
d =
    0.4387
    0.3816
    0.7655
    0.7952
    0.1869
>> s
s =
    0.4898
    0.4456
    0.6463
    0.7094
    0.7547
>> a = minimizer(P,d,s)
a =
   -8.5995
>> d(1)/(d(1) - s(1))
d(3)/(d(3) - s(3))
d(4)/(d(4) - s(4))
ans =
   -8.5995
ans =
    6.4219
ans =
    9.2643
>> b = min(d(P)/(d(P) - s(P)))
b =
         0    3.6806         0
>> d(P)/(d(P) - s(P))

ans =

         0    3.6806         0
         0    6.4219         0
         0    6.6709         0
```

I created a function that minimizes the values of d/(d-s) for the indices in P. Is there a way to find that minimization using build-in features of MATLAB? Obviously the one-line expression (where I assign to b) does not work and I think I understand why; it's generating a 3x3 matrix with all permutations of indices in P on d and s and just finding the minimum row (maybe through a norm, but probably by just taking row-sums). Is there an expression that would behave like the function?

Comment: Alright, update to question! A new application of elegance is needed.

Comment: aaaand answered my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Divakar points out, the solution is w(P). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For edit 2, there's an element-wise division operator and a vector-wise division operator. 
b = d(P)./(d(P) - s(P)) (with the dot) was what I needed.